# Sum by year and id in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to understand the most compact way to replicate the following Stata command in Python 2.7 using pandas:
`egen yr_id_sum = total(var_to_sum), missing by(id year)`.

I'd like to produce the yr_id_sum column in this table:

```
id    year    value  yr_id_sum
1     2010    1      3
1     2010    2      3
1     2011    3      7
1     2011    4      7
2     2010    11     23
2     2010    12     23
2     2011    13     27
2     2011    14     27
```

I can do this for one grouping variable as follows (this may help clarify what I'm trying to do):

```
def add_mean(grp):
    grp['ann_sum'] = grp['var_to_sum'].sum()
    return grp

df=df.groupby('year').apply(add_sum)
```

This is equivalent to `egen year_sum = total(var_to_sum), missing by(year)`.

I'm having difficulty with expanding answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798229/python-pandas-how-to-do-group-by-on-a-multiindex) about using sums with a multiindex to my case.

```
df.set_index(['year', 'id'], inplace=True)
df=df.groupby(['year', 'id').apply(add_sum)
```

Seems like it should do what I want it to... but I get `Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`

Here are some of the answers that I've already looked at:

- This question about [applying a user defined function to each subgroup of a Group By in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480774/applying-a-user-defined-function-to-each-subgroup-of-group-by-in-pandas) is close to what I am looking for.
- I am trying to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100490/summarize-grouped-data-in-pandas-while-filtering-after-the-group-part), with an unconditional sum.

Comment: Added data, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To reproduce your desired output, you could use `transform`: it takes the results of a groupby operation and broadcasts it back up to the original index.  For example:

```
>>> df["yr_id_sum"] = df.groupby(["id", "year"])["value"].transform(sum)
>>> df
   id  year  value  yr_id_sum
0   1  2010      1          3
1   1  2010      2          3
2   1  2011      3          7
3   1  2011      4          7
4   2  2010     11         23
5   2  2010     12         23
6   2  2011     13         27
7   2  2011     14         27
```

which is basically

```
>>> df.groupby(["id", "year"])["value"].sum()
id  year
1   2010     3
    2011     7
2   2010    23
    2011    27
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

but repeated to match the original columns being used as the index.

Comment: Great! This works perfectly. I was struggling with what to do with the error, because the duplicates were precisely what I was trying to sum over. I'll give you an upvote as soon as I have enough reputation.